# Add items to a list of objects, where the list itself is of type T

Tags: c#, list, generics, createinstance

```
private void Call()
{
    List<int> numbers= Get<List<int>>();
    MessageBox.Show("Numbers amount " + numbers.Count);
}

private T Get<T>() 
{
    T list = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    int a = 1;
    //HOW TO ADD "A" TO THE T-object [which is a list...]?
    return list;
}
```

Is it possible to let "T" be a List? I mean, it is possible (it compiles), **but how do you add an object to these kind of lists?**

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you call `Get<Exception>()`?

Comment: What this code is supposed to do? It is unclear..

Comment: Will it always be a list? How it will behave with different argument?

Comment: Although it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, note that you can use a [`new()` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) on parameters to allow you to do `new T()` rather than calling `Activator.CreateInstance()`, which is far more efficient.

Comment: Your code seems muddled in that the "generic" method assumes a very specific thing, namely, that we're dealing with a list of integers. Possibly you inted for `Get<T>` to *return* a `List<T>`, not a `T`.

Comment: @oyvind berg, You're saying `T` should not be specific to any kind,  and that you don't want to constrain it to collection types. At the same time, you're hardcoding in a call to `Add`, which is only supported on types that implement `ICollection<T>`. This makes no sense.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I thought about that, but then how would you resolve that with the hardcoded addition of an integer? How can you add an integer to the `List<string>` returned by our hypothetical `Get<string>()`, for example?

Comment: Given your proposed implementatino of the method the *only* valid value for `T` is a `List<int>`.  If that's the case, why is the method generic in the first place?

Comment: @Servy You can also have other collection types.

Comment: @Asad: you can't. Since I can't read minds, all I can do is try to coax the OP into telling us what he's trying to achieve. It's pointless for me to come up with working code if I don't know the problem.

Comment: @Asad The method is still not adding any real value.  You'd be better off just calling the constructor of that type and adding the  item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
private static T Get<T>() where T : IList
{
    T list = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 
    int a = 1;
    (list as IList).Add(a);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Lovely! So all these hours I was only an "I" away (casted to List instead of the interface IList)... And the "where T : IList" I've removed and rather checking the type within the "Get()", well, details.. Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually need the `as` cast here, since `list` is already an instance of a type that necessarily implemements `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `T` is always supposed to have the ability to add integers, what you're essentially saying is it implements `ICollection<int>`. Once you add `ICollection<int>` as a type constraint, you should be able to do this pretty easily:

```
private T Get<T>() where T: ICollection<int>, new
{
    T coll = new T();
    int a = 1;

    coll.Add(a);
    return coll;
}
```

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109056/add-items-to-a-list-of-objects-where-the-list-itself-is-of-type-t?noredirect=1#comment42721684_27109056), you can also avoid `Activator.CreateInstance` since you don't need any constructor arguments.

Now you can use:

```
var myList = Get<List<int>>();
Console.WriteLine(myList.Count); // Should be 1
```

Here is a demonstration: http://ideone.com/0pjFoJ

Answer (score 0):

What Asad said, but if you want a generic method to get a list, I would propose calling it GetList and doing the following (notice that adding is done in a lambda so you can add whatever you want or provide a function to do so):

```
private void Call()
        {
            List<int> numbers = GetList<int>(l =>
            {
                l.Add(1);
                l.Add(2);
                //etc
            });
            MessageBox.Show("Numbers amount " + numbers.Count);
        }

        private List<T> GetList<T>(Action<List<T>> initList)
        {
            List<T> list = Activator.CreateInstance<List<T>>();
            initList(list);
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: This is just a complicated way of writing `new List<int> { 1, 2 }` (which generalizes to other types just fine). I know what the OP is doing also seems needlessly complicated, but even so, if this were a solution to anything, the issue would be with the problem.

Comment: :) If the question was straight-forward the answe would be too